# SilverStripe CMS Unity3D Web Player Embedding Issue

Tags: javascript, html, unity-game-engine, silverstripe

I am trying to add the Unity3D (www.unity3d.com) web player into my site with SilverStripe CMS version 2.4.5. What seems to happen is that SS is dynamically removing my code that contains the web player. It leaves a closing div tag.

it is really simple for a simple static page to embed the web player. You need the following code and it works perfectly. 
HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/UnityObject.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  <!-- 
   //gets the unityPlayer div and replaces the content with an embed tag which is the web player made by Unity (it works outside of SS.) 
  function GetUnity() { 
     if (typeof unityObject != "undefined") { 
        return unityObject.getObjectById("unityPlayer"); 
     } 
     return null; 
  } 
  //sets the parameters of the web player 
  if (typeof unityObject != "undefined") { 
     unityObject.embedUnity("unityPlayer", "MazePuzzle.unity3d", 720, 450); 

  } 
  --> 
  </script>

<div id="unityPlayer"> 
        <div class="missing"> 
           <a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now!"> 
              <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now!" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/installation/getunity.png" width="193" height="63" /> 
           </a> 
        </div> 
     </div>
```

Comment: can you post your silverstripe .ss template file and the HTML that results when you view it using a browser?

Answer (score 1):

it's considered bad practice inserting javascript in you content fields, that's why the wysiwyg editor removes script elements. you can get around this though by configuring tinymce (see [this thread](http://silverstripe.org/content-editor-discussions/show/10520) for more info how to do this).

a better approach might be using shortcodes, as supported in silverstripe 2.4+. you could end up with something like this in your editor:

[unity width=720 height=450]MazePuzzle.unity3d[/unity]

the [docs](http://api.silverstripe.org/2.4/sapphire/misc/ShortcodeParser.html) on shortcodes are a bit sparse, but you can find a good tutorial on this on [ssbits](http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/2-4-using-short-codes-to-embed-a-youtube-video/)

Comment: 1- the javascript is added using the "requirements" tag of silverstripe. 2- Everything works fine, except that when the JS runs to do its thing, when it finds the plugin, it removes the content within <div id="unityPlayer"> after which it inserts an <embed> tag which makes the game run. (When outside of silverstripe, it does work) For some reason, silverstripe prevents the new code from being inserted in the page.

Comment: do you have a url to see this live? just the rendered page?

Comment: Unfortunalty i do not have it hosted, but i've been trying a bunch of things today and i've tried putting the code directly in the mypage.ss file and same thing. Here is the code silverstripe removes automatically:

<div id="unityPlayer" style="width: 720px; height: 450px; visibility: visible; "> 
<embed type="application/vnd.unity" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; " width="720" height="450" firstframecallback="unityObject.firstFrameCallback();" src="http://localhost:8888/SilverStripe-v2.4.5/assets/Uploads/MazePuzzle.unity3d"> 
</embed> 
</div>

Comment: Shortcode parsing is definitely the best way to do this - I've used it for code syntax highlighting, for example (see https://github.com/hamishcampbell/silverstripe-pastie/blob/master/code/PastieSnippet.php#L123 for an example).

Comment: I am not sure if the shortcode will work. The HTML markup for the Unity player is dynamically changed by the JavaScript...